# Groupby and sorting the same column

Tags: python, sqlite

How can I sort and goupby on a column in sqlite. I am trying to do it in Python.

```
query = '''
  SELECT Agency, COUNT(*) AS NumComplaints
    FROM data
    GROUP BY UPPER(Agency)
    ORDER BY -Agency
    
'''
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, disk_engine)
df.tail(50)
```

There is no impact of ORDER BY here. What should I do to sort the  Agency column in desending order.

I tried using `Orderby Agency DESC` and `ORDER BY -Agency`. No impact of ORDER BY here. I am getting the same out put.

Comment: Unless `Agency` is a number, it makes no sense to use `-Agency`.

Comment: It should work out of the box with `Orderby Agency DESC`. Can you add some debug?

Comment: Furthermore, if `Agency` is a string (even a number stored as a string/varchar) ordering will be lexicographical, not numerical. It's unclear what sort you are wanting and why `ORDER BY Agency DESC` isn't working for you, as that is the correct way of sorting the data. Sample data and desired results would help a lot to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning an alias an ordering by that.

```
SELECT UPPER(Agency) AS agency_upper, COUNT(*) AS Num=Complaints
FROM data
GROUP BY agency_upper
ORDER BY agency_upper DESC
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Luh4DJSuu5xvkGfvDTcWM/0)

Without this, you're ordering by a random element within each group, and these could be a mix of uppercase and lowercase, which affects the ordering.

Comment: I am not sure, but i think you cant use alias in GROUP BY.

Comment: You can: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Luh4DJSuu5xvkGfvDTcWM/0

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right. I normally use SQLServer and I believe in SQLServer doesn't allow it. I don't know if SQLite allows it or not.

Comment: SQLite and MySQL both allow it. The demo I linked to uses SQLite.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know

Answer (score 1):

First off: **Are you sure** you're trying to sort on Agency, and not Count (why else would you want to sort in DESC order?)

SQLite uses a case-insensitive sort by default, so I don't believe grouping on `UPPER(Agency)` or `Agency` will make a difference. You can test that out here with this query:

```
with data as (
  select "police" as agency union all
  select "Transportation" union all
  select "transportation"
)   
SELECT UPPER(Agency), COUNT(*) AS NumComplaints
FROM data
GROUP BY Agency
ORDER BY 2 DESC -- or change to "ORDER BY 1" to order on agency
```

You can play play around with the query [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Luh4DJSuu5xvkGfvDTcWM/1).

Additionally, you can manually specify the collation whether you want it to group on a case-insensitive or case-sensitive string. For example:

```
-- ignore case: 'a' = 'A'
GROUP BY Agency COLLATE NOCASE
```

Or:

```
-- exact case: 'a' != 'A'
GROUP BY Agency COLLATE BINARY
```

[https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#:~:text=7.%20Collating%20Sequences](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#:%7E:text=7.%20Collating%20Sequences)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to sort by Agency only to learn if that is possible. I found that the reason my code was not working was because I was using - sign instead of DESC which don't work for non-integer.